# Time-dependent sections of a vector bundle?

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles, vector-fields

Are there any books dealing with time-dependent vector fields and more generally with time-dependent sections of a vector bundle?

Thanks

Comment: The bibliography [here](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/papers/pdf/2014a.pdf) may help.